# Как отфильтровать запрос по столбцу связанной таблицы?

Tags: laravel

Нужно получить либо все цвета, либо цвета определенного производителя, либо цвета определенной коллекции. Пока получилось сделать все, кроме производителя.

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $query = Color::with('collection.manufacturer');

    if ($request->has('collection')) {
        $query->where(function ($q) use ($request) {
            return $q->where('collection_id', $request->input('collection'))->firstOrFail();
        });
    }

    if ($request->has('manufacturer')) {
        # code...
    }

    $colors = $query->get();

    return view('colors.index', compact('colors'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выбрать цвета, которые принадлежат коллекции конкретного производителя можно так:

```
    if ($request->has('manufacturer')) {
        $query->whereHas('collection', function (Builder $query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('manufacturer_id', $request->input('manufacturer'));
        });
    }
```

С учетом того, что связь производитель-> коллекция - один ко многим.

Comment: Здравствуйте! С наступающим! Уже перестал найдется, что кто-то ответит. Связь один ко многим есть, но код почему-то не работает. Хотя за наводку спасибо, уже что-то. https://i.ibb.co/LPnZnp7/image.jpg https://i.ibb.co/RDfgYg9/image.jpg

Comment: Покажите как объявлена связь collection в модели Colors и Модель collection.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/NT3AgjfJ (Color) https://pastebin.com/m2MxbWn8 (Collection) https://pastebin.com/rR4j0m0a (Manufacturer)

Comment: В таблице colors точно есть поле collection_id? Проверьте что называется именно так.

Comment: Сделайте так:

      $query->whereHas('collection', function (Builder $query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('manufacturer_id', $request->input('manufacturer'));
        });

То есть без указания модели в выражении.